# Customizing Titles on the Fly with Code

Tags: plugins, theme-development, customization, title

I hope this question is easy. I want to customize my theme so that the post titles are created on the fly with code. For example, I might have a post where a price changes on the page 4 times a week, and I want to be able to change my  to say: Get Product X for $19.99 without having to manually edit a meta variable...

Is it possible to do?

Is there a wordpress function I can call to override the title using a plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't answer how you'll get your dynamic data with which to update your Post Title, but you can easily hook into the Post Title, using the `the_title` filter:

```
<?php
function mytheme_dynamic_title( $title ) {
     // do something to the Post Title, which is passed
     // into this function as the variable $title
     // and then return $title
     return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'mytheme_dynamic_title' );
?>
```

That should get you started with hooking into the Title.

Comment: Thanks, that looks perfect to me. I knew there must be something straight forward. To get the custom content for the title, I'm running my own plugin which I think I can just add this to customize what I need. Thanks again!